# ebean does not generate methods for inhereted annotated fields?

Tags: annotations, playframework-2.0, ebean

This works:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ExtendableTranslation extends Model {
    public String label;    
}

@Entity
public class LeagueT extends ExtendableTranslation {
   @Id
   public Integer id;
}
```

but if I move id field to the superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ExtendableTranslation extends Model {
    public String label;    

    @Id
    public Integer id;
}

@Entity
public class LeagueT extends ExtendableTranslation {

}
```

I have an error:

**[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: models.translations.LeagueT._ebean_setni_id(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V]**

It's the same for all other annotated fields (@ManyToOne, @OneToMany). Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: This should work, I have used the same configuration only my id was `private`. Try `clean` and refresh project, it should work. The relations must work, AFAIk they work in my 2.0.4 project!

Comment: thx, Adis! "play clean compile" really helps in such situations!

Comment: `play clean-all`, `play clean` or `play clean compile` don't prevent the exception from being thrown in my Play 2.2.1 project :/